# What is "↵" in Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, newline

What is this "↵" character returned from a textarea with multiple lines? All my searches (and reason) suggests it should be a newline such as `\n`.

But when `x.time` is set to content of a multi-line `textarea`, this does not work:

```
> x
{time: "one↵two↵three↵"}
> x.time
"one↵two↵three↵"
> x.time.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "___")
"one↵two↵three↵"
```

Whereas this works:

```
> x.time.replace(/↵/g,"___")
"one___two___three___"
```

Comment: An unicode character?

Comment: Because you are using it LITERALLY... It is not being displayed in-place of a new-line, you are using the [literal Unicode value](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21B5/index.htm). Obviously the second snippet would work.

Comment: So why doesn't `x.time.replace(/\n/gm, "___")` work?

Answer (score 1):

> What is this "↵" character returned from a textarea with multiple lines?

A representation of a newline in the console.

> ```
> x= { time: "one↵two↵three↵" }
> ```

You're typing a literal `↵` character in your string (and not pulling a real new line from the DOM). That isn't a new line. How the developer tools express a new line in debugging output and how they treat the same character in source code are two different things.

Comment: Yeah, impossible to know whether the OP really started out with a newline and then picked up ↵ from the console, or really started out with ↵ (U-21B5, "Downwards Arrow With Corner Leftwards").

Comment: So why doesn't `x.time.replace(/\n/gm, "___")` work?

Comment: To clarify (I updated question): `x.time` is grabbed from a textarea on the page, where user entered multiple lines.

Comment: @Ze'ev — It does work: https://jsbin.com/sulefatuni/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

`↵` is just a human-friendly representation of a newline in the console, like `\n` is in JavaScript (and C and other languages that use the same escape character).

Answer (score -1):

## very simple it means the end of the line

one↵two↵three↵

one /n /n three /n

when you convert text area into string it gives you one of those example. for every line you will get this(↵|/n)